# Codeigniter Template

Tags: templates, codeigniter

UPDATE: so it looks like locally `<?= $content ?>` does not register as php code in my current local php settings.  Does anybody know how to change this?

Old Question:
I recently transfered my CI project that uses [Template library](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html) to a new local machine however it seems that the template no longer renders views and/or data into the template but instead just loads the template itself.  I've played around with the configuration all night but with no success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your php.ini's `short_open_tag` is disabled.

CI allows the on-the-fly rewriting of these tags if you want to use them.

Look in the config file.

Comment: yeah just had to mod apache settings.  The alternative is to just use the full tag with the echo statement.

Answer (score 1):

its because your wamp is not configuered for short_open_tag,click on wamp icon in the task bar 
scroll to php >>>> php settings and check short_open_tag.
restart your wamp, and all done.:)